# How to Restore a old Backup from SQL Server 7 SP4 to newest SQL Server versions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups, database-restore, sql-server-7

I'm trying to restore an very old code of mine, in that time the database was ms access and then I upgraded to SQL Server 7 SP4, now I want to restore those old backup, but SQL Server 2014 does not allow this..

So I would like to know how can I get to restore those backup, without installing SQL Server 7 ..

Thx U

Comment: Do you happen to have an instance of 2005 or 2008 running?

Comment: just 2014, I would have to install 2005 then.. like @Dean said..

Answer (score 4):

It's a 'three-version' rule. For example, to SQL Server 2012 one can only restore databases from 2008R2, 2008 and 2005 versions. Similarly, SQL Server 7 database can be restored to 2005, but no later version. To restore it to 2014, you will (by the rule) have to restore it to 2005, take a backup on 2005 and restore it to 2012, and only then 2012 backup restore to 2014. However, there is an exception: 2014 acknowledges the 2005 SP4, so you can skip the second step, and restore straight from 2005 to 2014 (but only from 2005 SP4).

Comment: @Mihai It says: "Upgrade a SQL Server 7.0 database to SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005 by attaching the database to an instance running either. Then you can upgrade the database to SQL Server 2008."